# Is Zoom Original Sound still free?

Tags: zoom-meeting

The company I’m with provides music lessons and our teachers and students have been having problems with enabling the Original Sound feature recently (for the past several months apparently actually) and I’m trying to figure out what the problem is exactly.

There seem to be some changes to Zoom's pricing model as well as the new global minimum software requirements that started in February 2023 and I’m wondering if one or both of these changes have impacted the ability for users to use Original Sound.

It’s not clear at the moment from Zoom’s documentation whether the Original Sound feature requires a paid subscription to be able to use it. Their docs state that to use it you need a basic account with a credit card. Which means what exactly? Based on my own tests the feature appears to be available while joining a meeting without even logging in which seems to indicate that you don’t need a paid subscription or even an account at all for that matter.

Has anyone been able to confirm with Zoom directly whether or not the original sound should still be available to basic user accounts? I’ve tried reaching out to support but no response yet.

Or maybe the problems they are experiencing lately are related to the new global minimum Zoom version requirements not being met since the strict enforcement started in February if users are using outdated Zoom versions?

Reference to docs regarding original sounds needing a basic account with a credit card:
https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/115003279466-Configuring-audio-for-music-and-singing

Reference to global minimums software versions required to use original sound:
https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360046244692

Comment: Have you tried contacting Zoom support?

Comment: @Gantendo yeah and they confirmed that no paid subscription is required to use original sound. And they said that users using outdated versions of Zoom could cause the feature not to work but that they would like to confirm that by investigating specific meeting ids where it was an issue. So they opened a support ticket and I will be following up with them once I investigate myself a bit further. The other possibility I think is that some people don't seem to realize that you have to enable the feature in both general settings and again during an actual meeting.